# Why doesn't the remotePatterns wildcard work for specific images in Next.js?

Tags: next.js

I'm using newsapi.org and Nextjs image component.

To use images from api i had to configure my next.config.js to accept images from any domains.
In general it works, it work for most of domains but a moment ago I again got an error about invalid src prop. I think it maybe something with that dot after .com/
I don't really ask for help because i can just simply keep my conifig modified like i di but I want to know why wildcard doesn't work for that specific image

```
Error: Invalid src prop (https://www.si.com/.image/ar_1.91%2Cc_fill%2Ccs_srgb%2Cfl_progressive%2Cg_faces:center%2Cq_auto:good%2Cw_1200/MTk2ODA2NjcwMTU0NzM2NzAy/dawn-staley.jpg) on `next/image`, hostname "www.si.com" is not configured under images in your `next.config.js`
See more info: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/next-image-unconfigured-host
```

When i started my project my next.config.js looked like this

```
const nextConfig = {
  reactStrictMode: true,
  images: {
    remotePatterns: [
      {
        protocol: "https",
        hostname: "**",
      }
    ],
  },
};
```

I tried also adding wildcard to pathname but it doesn't work.

It works if I add a 2nd object that looks like this

```
      {
        protocol: "https",
        hostname: "www.si.com",
        port: "",
        pathname: "/.image/**",
      },
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this exact problem too.

First thing, I think this might be a bug on Next.js part. This might be a related GitHub issue: https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/46903

Either way, I dug around and came up with 2 solutions.

The first one is more specific. Add this pattern to allow paths that start with `/.image`:

```
{
  protocol: "https",
  hostname: "**",
  pathname: "/.image/**",
}
```

The second one is a bit more generic. I speculate that the problem resides in the fact that the pathname contains a dot `.` and when Next.js parses it, something wrong happens - could be a bug in Next.js or maybe it's intentional that this is the way it's being handled, not sure. Either way, add this pattern to allow pathnames that contain `.` in them:

```
{
  protocol: "https",
  hostname: "**",
  pathname: "**/.*/**",
}
```

I think even the second option would fail if the pathname was like `/.image/someStringHere/.data/dataId/imageName.jpg` because it would have two parts with dot `.`, so I think this solution is not a definite one but at least it kind of works. You can try messing around with the examples I provided and maybe you would be able to come up with a better solution - would appreciate it if you commented if you did find a more general solution.